# Implementation of Battery in Android Emulators Under Maui

Tags: android, maui, battery, device-emulation

Is there a setting or permission missing?

When we execute the code

```
if (Battery.Default.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.Battery)
```

the thread in which it is running vanishes and does not throw an exception.

The emulated device right at the moment is "Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)".

Comment: `the thread in which it is running vanishes and does not throw an exception.` What do you mean by words `it is running vanishes`? Can you elaborate on your problem? And could you please post more code snippets so that we can try to reproduce this problem on my side?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Thread vanishing means other threads continue to run but the thread referencing the battery no longer exists.  You can replicate this issue by referencing anything to do with "Battery".  For example, you could attempt to retrieve Battery.ChargeLevel.

Comment: I could get the value of code `Battery.ChargeLevel` on my emulator, and the result was `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that

BATTERYSTATS

was not selected in

SolutionExplorer > YourProjectName > Platforms > Android > AndroidManifest.xml

The issue is that there was no permissions exception thrown.

Also, the issue arises on attempts to access the battery from other than SolutionExplorer > YourProjectName > Platforms > Android > MainActivity.cs.  This may be a bug.

Comment: Could you please accept you reply as an answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)